# disk encryption with stream cipher(s) on Linux with cryptsetup/dm-crypt?

Tags: linux, luks

I have been trying without success to use cryptsetup - in both modi plain or LUKS - to create a device with a stream cipher [Chacha20*, ARC4] instead of one of the default block ciphers.

Behaviour is the same for different distributions/kernels (Fedora, Ubuntu), where the kernel supports the ciphers in principle [/proc/crypto, /lib/modules/*/kernel/crypto/]

For Chacha20, chacha20poly1305 cryptsetup fails during creation since no cbc-plain support (default is available) - which I suppose is reasonable for a stream cipher not to care about block modi.

For RC4, I can create a a device and access it, but after closing reopening fails with the device not being redable.

My approach for RC4:

```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/container bs=1M count=200
> dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/keyfile bs=1k count=8
> cryptsetup --cipher arc4 --key-file=/tmp/keyfile open --type plain /dev/shm/container ramdisk
> mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/ramdisk
> echo "test" > /dev/mapper/ramdisk/test.foo
> cryptsetup close ramdisk

> cryptsetup --cipher arc4 --key-file=/tmp/keyfile open --type plain /dev/shm/container ramdisk
  -- fails
```

When using LUKS, the header information looks like

```
> cryptsetup luksDump /dev/shm/container 
 LUKS header information for /dev/shm/container
 Version:        1
 Cipher name:    arc4
 Cipher mode:    cbc-plain
 Hash spec:      sha256
 Payload offset: 4096
```

Actually, I can format the device with different arc-modi-IV combinations as well - I suppose the plain container uses as default also cbc-plain (which does not sound reasonable, or?).

My assumption is, that cryptsetup/dm-crypt does not support stream ciphers and that failing as for chacha20 should be the default behaviour and arc4 is not catched gracefully??

Question is, if this assumption is correct or how it would be possible to use stream ciphers with dm-crypt?

Comment: background: I wanted to benchmark RC4 as cipher since on my Raspberry Pi without AES-NI performance with AES as cipher is 'suboptimal'. Threat model is just to encrypt a USB drive without sensitiv data, so I can discard it easily if it would be failing. So, RC4 would be fine as a better-than-nothing solution - prefered cipher would be Chacha20, if performace would be OK and if there would be an easily deployable kernel module for Raspbian

Comment: RC4 is trivially breakable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security

Comment: as said, ARC4 would still fit my threat model, assuming that an attacker would only be able to access one state of data in rest, i.e., an unpower USB drive. Any attack would require afais frequent access to the storage between modifications in the fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the cryptsetup issue tracker I got informed, that only block ciphers but no stream ciphers are supported. Thus, the consistent behaviour should presumably be for ARC4 as for Chacha20, i.e., failing but not allowing to create a device/container.

see https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/issues/301